# Leaflet Markers movement on specified routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to move tags from one position to another using below code.

"https://jsfiddle.net/ashwincoool/90ojwhy7/20/"

But in this code tags are jumping from start point to end point. As per our requirement we need to show proper movement instead of jumping from start to end point.

In above mentioned script route points are present in 'simulation_points' array but it's not traversing with the route point but making a jump from start point to end.

Expected movement like is
[image]

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-animations (in particular, https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Marker.SlideTo )